# IronPython, Click Once, .NET 2.0 Error - thoughts?

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, ironpython

I'm am trying to roll out a test application to test the feasibility of righting a Click Once Smart Client app that also uses a rules engine customizable by embedding IronPython.

So far all users but me get this error (below) when invoking the script engine.

Do I need to do something special to force deployment of the IronPython and Scripting assemblies? I thought that would be automatic because they were referenced in my project.
Is this just not feasible in .NET 2.0?

Thoughts?

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(System.String, System.Type, System.Type[], Boolean)'.
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.Helpers.CreateDynamicMethod(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes)
   at Microsoft.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.Snippets.CreateDynamicMethod(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes)
   at Microsoft.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CreateDynamicLambdaCompiler(CompilerScope scope, String methodName, Type returnType, IList`1 paramTypes, IList`1 paramNames, Boolean closure, Boolean emitDebugSymbols, Boolean forceDynamic)
   at Microsoft.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CompileLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, Type delegateType, Boolean emitDebugSymbols, Boolean forceDynamic, MethodInfo& method)
   at Microsoft.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CompileLambda[T](LambdaExpression lambda, Boolean emitDebugSymbols)
   at Microsoft.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression.Compile[T](Boolean emitDebugSymbols)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.OptimizedScriptCode.InvokeTarget(LambdaExpression code, Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at UAP.UI.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 4):

IronPython requiers .NET 2.0SP1 or later to run.  This exception is happening due to an overload that was added in SP1.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click your project and go to `Properties` theres a `Publish` tab, that allows you to specify prerequisite installs for your application.

Presumably you can supply a path to the IronPython install executable here.

Comment: But I shouldn't have to install it right? Just push down the 3 assemblies needed right? IronPython.dll, Microsoft.Scripting.dll, Microsoft.Scripting.Code.dll - But how can I tell if these 3 assemblies need 3.0 or 3.5 to run properly?

Comment: You also need Microsoft.Scripting.ExtensionAttribute.dll, and you probably want IronPython.Modules.dll. You absolutely don't need to install and you don't need .NET 30 or 3.5, but you do need SP1 of .NET 2.0.

(If you have 3.5 installed, then you automatically have 2.0 SP1.)