# Modern Equivalent of Visual Studio 6 "Depends" utility

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dependencies

Is there a good tool that will look at a .NET assembly and tell you all of the dependencies it has on other assemblies? Sort of like the old depends.exe from VS6 days.

**UPDATE**
I guess the one thing that I am missing from Reflector is verion #'s. Unless I am missing something. How do I tell what framework is required by an assembly?

I'm trying to solve this other issue I am having:
[IronPython, Click Once, .NET 2.0 Error - thoughts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922681/ironpython-click-once-net-2-0-error-thoughts)

From the error message it looks like I need:
Microsoft.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.Snippets
Microsoft.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler

Other than the app blowing up on me... how should I have detected a need here?
It runs fine on my machine.

Is this a 3.0 or 3.5 thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Umm, [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)?

Edit:  To find detailed information on the assemblies required by a given assembly, load the assembly into Reflector, and expand the namespace. You should see the assembly name listed.  Expand that and you will see "References".  Expand References to view the assemblies required.  Selecting one of those will give version and name info below.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure whether it always used to be, but .NET Reflector is a paid product (with a free trial period).

Answer (score 4):

The FusionLog utilities should help you track down what assemblies are being looked for and where it was searching for and finding them, or not.  It will also tell you the version being searched for.  (And it comes as part of the .NET SDK)

Answer (score 3):

The best equivalent of depends.exe for .NET, i.e. a tool that shows what assemblies are loaded **at runtime** (as opposed to Reflector's static(?) analysis) is the *[MS Assembly Binding Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/e74a18c4(v=vs.71))* (or *fuslogvw* among friends :)

It logs all assembly loading infomation - including dinamically loaded assemblies.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC65195.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com)
But I think it is not free.

EDIT: [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)
Open the assembly. Right click -> Analyze. It will show which assemblies, the current assembly depends upon.

Comment: NDepend isn't equivalent to 'depends.exe' - it shows code dependency, not which DLL files are required and their versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a tool that comes with the Microsoft SDK (rather than third party) use `ildasm.exe`, the .NET assembly disassembler. While it won't show code in anything but IL, it will show metadata, names and assembly dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) has some [addins](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins) that should help with this.

Answer (score 0):

### DependencyWalker for .NET

[DependencyWalker for .NET](https://github.com/isindicic/DependencyWalker.Net) shows dependencies tree for .NET assemblies like old Dependency Walker show it for non managed applications. To quickly start to use it, get latest [DependencyWalker.zip](https://github.com/isindicic/DependencyWalker.Net/releases/download/1.0/DependencyWalker.zip) and unzip it somewhere.  (The link is to the latest version at the time of writing).

This works with .NET Framework dependencies (here is an example for a simple WPF .NET app):

[image: UI for DependencyWalker.NET]

There is also a list of references:

[image: DependencyWalker.NET - list of references]

However, for .NET Core applications, I can see the list of some - but not all - dependencies YMMV...:

[image: .NET Core app in DependencyWalker.NET]