# How to find missing assemblies?

Tags: .net, dll

I am working on an .NET Windows application. I have deployed my application to my client. I am facing a problem that one of the assemblies from the deployment directory is missing.

Is there any way to find which assembly is missing? Say if assembly1 has a reference to assembly2 and assembly2 is missing from the deployment directory...is there any tool Microsoft recommends to find the missing assembly?

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is what you are looking for.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922943/modern-equivalent-of-visual-studio-6-depends-utility) also has other suggestions.

Comment: The [SharpDevelop](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/) Team is working at the moment on [a free alternative](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx).

Comment: Even better.  Got to love the Mono dev team.

Comment: Not Mono, SharpDevelop. They're unaffiliated as far as I know.

Comment: Oh you're right, I was thinking monoDevelop. Getting my open source IDE's all mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the NetOMatix utility [Depends.Net](http://www.netomatix.com/development/DependsNet.aspx).