# Protobuf-net file or assembly not found when referencing assembly over COM interop

Tags: c#, com, interop, protobuf-net

I am trying to write a wrapper in C# for the protobuf-net package to enable me to access protocol buffer files directly from VBA in excel.
I have written my code with references to protobuf-net added through the nuget package manager.  I have made my assembly COM visible and from VBA I am able to access my classes.
However when I try to load a protobuffer file, I get the following message:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.668,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (ProtoBufInterface.OutputData)"

I have checked that the protobuf-net.dll file is being copied to the assembly directory.  Any ideas what is causing this or what I can do to fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: eugh; COM dependencies are a royal pain; as a lazy horrible hack just to see if it works: does it work OK if you install it (protobuf-net) in the GAC?

Comment: Hey Marc.  Thanks for the quick response.  Apologies I am quite new to this - could you please explain how I can install protobuf-net in the GAC?  Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool

Comment: The way the CLR searches for dependent assemblies does not change for a [ComVisible] assembly.  It looks in the GAC first, in the directory of the EXE next.  And *not* in the directory in which you stored your DLL.  Using the GAC or a regfree manifest for the client app is highly recommended, COM has a pretty nasty DLL Hell problem since registration is machine-wide.   Which solves this problem as well.  Test your code by copying the DLLs into the same directory as the client EXE.  Consider ILMerge to generate a single executable file.

Comment: I tried registering protobuf-net.dll in the GAC but I still get the same error.  I also tried looking at dependencies in .NET reflector, but the only references inside protobuf-net.dll are mscorlib, System, and System.Xml.  So as Mark says there should not be anything missing.

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem using .NET Reflector.
I am referencing two other libraries, one is protobuf-net.dll and the other is a third party library which itself references protobuf-net.dll.
The problem was that the version referenced in the third party library (2.0.0.668) was different to the one I had installed (2.3.3).  Actually in hindsight the error message told me everything I needed.
Replacing my protobuf-net.dll reference with teh 2.0.0.668 version fixed my problem.  I did not need to separately register protobuf-net.dll in the GAC.

Thank you all for the help along the way.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: great to hear! in .NET-land, you can use assembly binding redirects to hack around this; not sure how that would work in terms of COM interop, though

Answer (score 0):

protobuf-net.dll also depends on other DLLs which you should add into your references.

If they are not explicitly specified, you should use a utility like "depends.net". More info can be found in this link:

[Modern Equivalent of Visual Studio 6 "Depends" utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922943/modern-equivalent-of-visual-studio-6-depends-utility)

Comment: protobuf-net doesn't have any non-standard dependencies; assuming we're talking full framework (because: COM interop) - everything should be in the GAC. To quote from nuget: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKCk2.png